# How can NTP/Interrupts affect timers?

Tags: java, time, ntp

I have a loop, A, running every `n` seconds (probably will be around .5 or 1 seconds or so). I have another task, B, that happens roughly every `5n` seconds, but this task occurs in a completely separate environment and server.

I need to ensure that task A happens at least once in between times task B occurs. However, I am worried about the following cases:

- NTP adjustments messing with the time on either server.
- Interrupts or GC running and slowing task A, delaying its execution.

Is there any way to resolve these potential point of failures?

These will be implemented in Java but I would imagine it is fairly language independent.

Comment: How important is it that B doesn't run twice without A running in between? I can't imagine a way to ensure this without a coordinating service to ensure that the jobs run transactionally.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way of guaranteeing that task B won't execute if task A hasn't run without using a coordinating service. Beyond the problems with clock skew and process suspension there are other issues may run in to. What happens if task A fails because of hardware/resource errors? What about service restarts?

The simplest fix would be to make task B tolerant of the case where task A hasn't run. If you can't do that then you'll have to provide a service to track the state of task A. The lightest way of implementing this is to issue each run of A with a unique ID and check it before running B.

Something like:

```
public class TaskA implements Runnable {
    @Resource
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Run task A
        // ...

        // Set run ID for task B to retrieve
        taskService.setRunId("A", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}

public class TaskB implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskB.class);

    @Resource
    private TaskService taskService;

    private String lastId;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String nextId = taskService.getRunId("A");
        if (this.lastId == null) {
            log.info("First run. Not executing");
        } else if (lastId.equals(nextId)) {
            log.warn("Task A has not run. Refusing to execute");
        } else {
            log.info("Executing");
            // Run task B
            // ...
        }
        this.lastId = nextId;
    }
}
```

I've used a UUID in the above example to avoid the need for a persistent store to guarantee unique IDs. You could use a database if you have one in the environment. I'd avoid the use of timestamps for the reasons you've noted (clock skew etc.).